# Graphical user interface over remote ipython kernel

Tags: python, linux, kernel, ipython

I have succesfully connected to a ipython kernel on a remote machine using 
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook:-Connecting-to-a-remote-kernel-via-ssh

The thing is however that any things I do (just like `pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4])`) opens a figure on the server and not on my client. Moreover I have programmed a Graphical User Interface with chaco with the same problem: opening the GUI via a ipython console on my client (`chacoobject.edit_traits()`), opens it on the server and not the client...

Is there a workaround? I'm running Windows 7 on my server and Ubuntu on my client if that matters
Thansks